# Unexpected Behaviour of C program

Tags: c

Below is a C program which wants to multiply an integer by 5 using bitwise operation. But when i run this program it gives unexpected output. I know there is something i messing up which i could not see. Any help regarding this guys and girls ?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #define PrintInt(expr) printf("%s : %d\n",#expr,(expr))
  int FiveTimes(int a)
  {
      int t;
      t = a<<2 + a;
      return t;
  }

  int main()
  {
      int a = 1, b = 2,c = 3;
      PrintInt(FiveTimes(a));
      PrintInt(FiveTimes(b));
      PrintInt(FiveTimes(c));
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: In what sense in the output unexpected? What is the actual output and how does it differ from the desired result?

Comment: the output is :  FiveTimes(a) : 8   FiveTimes(b) : 32   FiveTimes(c) : 96. But the output should be multiple of 5.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more information. Do not post extra info as a comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question of "operator precedence": "<<" has a lower priority than "+" - so your code actually calculates `a << (2 + a)`, while it should be `(a << 2) + a`. The latter is the fix.

Comment: Thanks got it. It was a puzzle question. I spent a lot time. There are something which are minute that we underestimate them and look for bigger problems.

Comment: First day I was in a 'computer class', decades ago, I was taught 'use extra brackets to keep your expressions clear and to avoid precedence issues - redundant brackets cost nothing and missing brackets cause bugs'.  Is this not taught any more?